# How to move the product price next to add to cart button

Tags: javascript, css, woocommerce, hook

I am trying to move the product price next to add to cart button. I have tried the following and it move the price under the button and not next to add to cart button. Any ideas?[image]

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 30 );
```

Comment: can you post more source code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you would make a copy of the woocommerce template and tweak it.

But if that's not possible, you can try a different approach.

I'm using the [StoreFront WooCommerce theme](https://themes.woocommerce.com/storefront/product/nikon-mb-d17-multi-battery-power-pack/) for this example

Locate the woocommerce price classname - here we have `woocommerce-Price-amount`

[image]

---

and reposition it by adding CSS in `style.css` - in this case we needed

```css
position: absolute;
transform: translate(281px, 147px);
```

---

[image]

Comment: @Rob this is an explanation of a technique that has to be adapted to fit the case at hand. We don't have enough information in the question to provide detailed on-point instructions.

Comment: If you don't have enough information, you need to vote to close the question for that reason.

Comment: Thanks Silviu for the clear explanation. It's very helpful.